How to get a user username by a Discord?
I'm trying to get a user Discord username by a Discord bot using Discord.js V14.
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is ready');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content = '!username') {
        const username = message.author.username;
        message.channel.send(`Your username is: ${username}`);
    }
});

client.login('your-bot-token');


I hope it can help you. Here, some things that maybe solve your problem:

Equality operator: You should use === for comparison instead of = which is an assignment operator.
Event name: For the class Client the correct event name for handling messages is messageCreate, not message.

const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

// Create a new client instance with necessary intents
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.MESSAGE_CONTENT
    ]
});

// Event triggered when the bot is ready
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is ready');
});

// Event triggered when a message is created
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    // Check if the message content is '!username'
    if (message.content === '!username') {
        // Get the username of the message author
        const username = message.author.username;
        // Send the username back to the channel
        message.channel.send(`Your username is: ${username}`);
    }
});

// Log in to Discord with your bot token
client.login('your-bot-token');


